# How to get knowledge article publish via REST?

Tags: rest-api, knowledge, c#

Reading https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_dev_guide.pdf

It looks to me like it should be possible to publish a master article and settranslation of articleversion via the REST service but I am unable to find the URLs endpoint for this in the rest explorer (workbench) or any example on the web.

I am using https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET and C#. I can't find any reference to knowledge in there as well but that should be easy to adjust when the service I need is available.

Any ideas how to get imported articles published via REST?

---

Hi Saroj,

Thanks for answering. Here is what I tried:

I added a function to the ForceClient.cs of the toolkit to expose the URL.

```
public Task<SuccessResponse> PublishArticleAsync(object record, string VersionId)
{
 if (record == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("record");
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(VersionId)) throw new ArgumentNullException("VersionId");

 return _serviceHttpClient.HttpPatchAsync(record, string.Format("/knowledgeManagement/articleVersions/masterVersions/{0}", VersionId));
 }
```

Create an ArticleVersion(KAV) via the API, this works fine, articleVersion (KAV) is created and on Draft. Since it’s new, the system seems to create an Article (KA) itself (I think?)

```
Salesforce.Common.Models.SuccessResponse CreateTask = await API.CreateArticle(DocType.APIArticleTypeVersion, Article);
```

To get the just created articleversion I perform a QueryAllAsync on the return id from the create task (returning the versionid: string q = "SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId, MasterVersionId FROM " + namespacePrefix + ArticleType_KA + " WHERE Id = '" + id + "'").

```
Salesforce.Common.Models.QueryResult<dynamic> FindTask = await API.FindArticleVersion(DocType.APIArticleTypeVersion, CreateTask.Id);
```

So far, so good. Created article is found and the MasterVersionId from it is retrieved. Next I want to publish it. So I pass the masterversionid which is present on the result)

```
Salesforce.Common.Models.SuccessResponse PublishTask = await API.PublishArticle(FindTask.Records[0]["MasterVersionId"]);
```

Which is implemented by

```
public async Task<SuccessResponse> PublishArticle(string VersionId)
{
dynamic Publish = new ExpandoObject();
Publish.publishStatus = "Online";
SuccessResponse Result = await client.PublishArticleAsync(Publish, VersionId);
return (Result);
}
```

Whatever id (articleid, masterversionid, id of the articleversion), I seem to pass, the result is always “The requested resource does not exists.”

I am obviously missing something here but just can’t find it...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works now, indeed missed a thing while changing the force.net toolkit. its should be:

```
public Task<SuccessResponse> PublishArticleAsync(object record, string VersionId)
{
if (record == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("record");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(VersionId)) throw new ArgumentNullException("VersionId");

return _serviceHttpClient.HttpPatchAsync(record, string.Format("knowledgeManagement/articleVersions/masterVersions/{0}", VersionId));
}
```

I removed the / before the knowledgemanagement in the url part because it created a malformed url. Articles versions are published now.

Answer (score 1):

To **Publish the Master Version of an Article** follow the endpoint and Salesforce documentation as below.

Endpoint: `/services/data/v25.0/knowledgeManagement/articleVersions/masterVersions/<versionId>`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_REST_publish_master_version.htm

Comment: Hi Saroj,
Added some additional research but can't get it to work.